# Universal Frameworks with Xcode 10

Tags: ios12, xcode10.1, ios-universal-framework

When we used this script in the post-action of the archive in my scheme to make a FAT binary framework. i.e., One that will work on the simulator and actual device.  Its working fine up to Xcode 9.3 But its not working script for Xcode 10.
  As per blogs we don't have universal framework support for Xcode 10. Please let us know how to achieve this from Xcode 10.

Thanks,

Comment: Any solution on this ?

Comment: @Nitish Not Yet. Do you have any recommendations..?

Comment: Indeed I do. Please check my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435488/run-script-for-universal-framework-on-xcode-10

Comment: @Nitish Still i am facing the same issue, Can you please let me know working solution

Comment: Hi Madhu, you can check this repo as an example: https://www.github.com/gurhub/surmagic. Best