# Run script for universal framework on Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios-frameworks, ios-universal-framework

I Xcode 9.x, I was using the below script which worked fine :

```
######################
# Options
######################

REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=false

FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"

SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"


######################
# Build Frameworks
######################

xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}"
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -sdk iphonesimulator
BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${IPHONE_SIMULATOR_BUILD_DIR}" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}"
ARCHS="i386 x86_64" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" $ACTION 2>&1

xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}"
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -sdk iphoneos
BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${IPHONE_DEVICE_BUILD_DIR}" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}"
ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" $ACTION 2>&1

######################
# Create directory for universal
######################

rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Copy files Framework
######################

cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Make an universal binary
######################

lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo

# For Swift framework, Swiftmodule needs to be copied in the universal framework
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
cp -f ${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
                                                                      fi

                                                                      if [ -d "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
                                                                      cp -f ${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
                                                                      fi

                                                                      ######################
                                                                      # On Release, copy the result to release directory
                                                                      ######################
                                                                      OUTPUT_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/Output/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"

                                                                      rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"
                                                                      mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

                                                                      cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$OUTPUT_DIR"

                                                                      if [ ${REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER} = true ]; then
                                                                      open "${OUTPUT_DIR}/"
                                                                      fi
```

This didn't for **Xcode 10**. Later I saw that there was some modification required in the script. So I followed [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711648/fat-framework-script-for-xcode-10) answer to set the script. But after setting this script, when I try to build the Universal framework, Xcode hangs on **Building script 1 of 1.**
I have been trying to look for the right solution but failing each time.
**What is the correct run script for a universal framework (covering all architectures) on Xcode 10 ?**

Comment: Hi Nitish, you can use this tool for possible future issues: https://github.com/gurhub/surmagic Best.

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks a lot @mgyky

Answer (score 5):

Adding `-UseModernBuildSystem=NO` to xcodebuild command should work.

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -UseModernBuildSystem=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator 2>&1

xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -UseModernBuildSystem=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos 2>&1
```

It should fix your problem.

This is the entire script I'm currently using and which successfully builds universal framework with Xcode 10. [Link to gist](https://gist.github.com/dhruvsbhatt/127b47c09e27ea981290236e22d78a08)

Currently, working to make use of latest build system to build universal framework. Shall update the answer soon.

Comment: I want to cry out of happiness ;( It works perfectly fine. Many thanks Dhruv

Comment: Cheers. :) Happy coding !

Comment: @Dhruv, url 404

Comment: @Dhruv can you please update the gist link?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "project"
#open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: Detected, stopping"
else
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iosuniversal

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
echo "iphone"
xcodebuild -target "${TARGET_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
echo "iphonesim"
xcodebuild -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

## Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
echo "universal"
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 3. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory
echo "iphone simulator path"
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"
fi

# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
echo "lipo create"
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

echo "end"
fi
```

First Generate the Separate build for both simulator and device
while opening your Products folder you will Find the separate build for both
And then use this Run script in your project

After Generating the Script you Find the Folder IOS-Universal in Same product Folder

For me Working fine.

The screenshots below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FITMr.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Open Terminal**, navigate **root directory** of project and **Replace YourUniversalFramework with your project Name and Scheme name(if Required)**, run the command after successful, It will generate **universal** folder **inside build**.

Framework from **universal folder** is now ready to be consumed by devices and simulators!

**Note:** Paste whole script on Terminal after changes and Run

[image]

***Command/Script For .xcodeproj Project***

```
mkdir build
    ;
    xcodebuild clean build \
      -project YourUniversalFramework.xcodeproj \
      -scheme YourUniversalFramework \
      -configuration Release \
      -sdk iphoneos \
      -derivedDataPath derived_data \
      BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES 
    ;
    mkdir build/devices
    ;
    cp -r derived_data/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/YourUniversalFramework.framework build/devices
    ;
    xcodebuild clean build \
      -project YourUniversalFramework.xcodeproj \
      -scheme YourUniversalFramework \
      -configuration Release \
      -sdk iphonesimulator \
      -derivedDataPath derived_data \
      BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
    ;
    mkdir build/simulator
    ;
    cp -r derived_data/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/ build/simulator/
    ;
    mkdir build/universal
    ;
    cp -r build/devices/YourUniversalFramework.framework build/universal/
    ;
    lipo -create \
      build/simulator/YourUniversalFramework.framework/YourUniversalFramework \
      build/devices/YourUniversalFramework.framework/YourUniversalFramework \
      -output build/universal/YourUniversalFramework.framework/YourUniversalFramework
    ;
    cp -r \
    build/simulator/YourUniversalFramework.framework/Modules/YourUniversalFramework.swiftmodule/* \
    build/universal/YourUniversalFramework.framework/Modules/YourUniversalFramework.swiftmodule/YourUniversalFramework
```

***Command/Script For .xcworkspace Project***

```
mkdir build
    ;
    xcodebuild clean build \
      -workspace YourUniversalFramework.xcworkspace \
      -scheme YourUniversalFramework \
      -configuration Release \
      -sdk iphoneos \
      -derivedDataPath derived_data \
      BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES 
    ;
    mkdir build/devices
    ;
    cp -r derived_data/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/YourUniversalFramework.framework build/devices
    ;
    xcodebuild clean build \
      -workspace YourUniversalFramework.xcworkspace \
      -scheme YourUniversalFramework \
      -configuration Release \
      -sdk iphonesimulator \
      -derivedDataPath derived_data \
      BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
    ;
    mkdir build/simulator
    ;
    cp -r derived_data/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/ build/simulator/
    ;
    mkdir build/universal
    ;
    cp -r build/devices/YourUniversalFramework.framework build/universal/
    ;
    lipo -create \
      build/simulator/YourUniversalFramework.framework/YourUniversalFramework \
      build/devices/YourUniversalFramework.framework/YourUniversalFramework \
      -output build/universal/YourUniversalFramework.framework/YourUniversalFramework
    ;
    cp -r \
    build/simulator/YourUniversalFramework.framework/Modules/YourUniversalFramework.swiftmodule/* \
    build/universal/YourUniversalFramework.framework/Modules/YourUniversalFramework.swiftmodule/YourUniversalFramework
```